# How to Change Image Saving Options with the Python API? (Color, Color Depth)

Tags: python, scripting, image, texture-baking

In my script I create an image, generate the image and then save it like this:

```
image = bpy.data.images.new('my_image', width=1024, height=1024)
# other code that generates the image by baking onto a texture node ...
image.filepath_raw = '//outputs/my_image.tif'
image.file_format = 'TIFF'
image.save()
```

But when saving the image I would like to have control over those options:

[image: screenshot of output options when saving from user interface]

...which are available when saving from the user interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can discover nearly all data paths from Blender GUI itself.

Set your mouse cursor over a field and a tooltip will appear:

[image]

You can also copy (part of) the path directly here:

[image]

Then you can use it (and test it) from the Python console, and also discover all the properties you need using autocompletion with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key:

[image]

So concretely you can for instance:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_mode = 'RGBA'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_depth = '8'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.compression = 20
```

You can now easily search in the documentation:

[image]

And have access to [a complete information for the fields values (click me)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings.html#bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings).